# How to authenticate WebApp from Exchange server 2013?

Tags: .net, exchange-server, exchangewebservices, outlook-web-app

I am building an app that fetches user's contacts from an on-premises exchange server using Exchange APIs. Current approach is to ask the user for username & password.

```
var service = new ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2013)
    {
         Credentials = new WebCredentials(credentials.UserName, credentials.Password),
         TraceEnabled = false,
         Url = new Uri("https://mail.*****.com/EWS/Exchange.asmx")
    };
```

I was wondering If It is possible to avoid asking for password If user is already logged-in from MS Oulook client?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the MS Exchange environment. If [Kerberos](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa378747(v=vs.85).aspx) is [enabled](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff808312(v=exchg.160).aspx) on the MS Exchange environment you might use it (but it depends how your application access EWS). Microsoft has an similar article for that here:
[EWS from a Web Application using Windows Authentication and Impersonation](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/emeamsgdev/2012/11/05/ews-from-a-web-application-using-windows-authentication-and-impersonation/)

Keep noted that Kerberos isn´t enabled per default and in most MS Exchange environments [NTLM](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa378749(v=vs.85).aspx) in place. Keep also noted that Kerberos works only via an Domain context. That means if the PC where Outlook (and your software) is running on isn´t joined to an active directory domain then Kerberos isn´t working (see also [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/455793/kerberos-authentication-for-workstations-not-on-domain)). But you might wish to check that in your code and if Kerberos works you might use it, if not then you can ask the user for a password (negotiate the authentication; you might wish to check this [here](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/exchange/2011/04/15/recommendation-enabling-kerberos-authentication-for-mapi-clients/)).